# Exporting environment (yml) file during conda build

Tags: python, build, anaconda, conda

**TLDR**
See question at the bottom

**Background/Intro**

I am still quite new to the world of Python and Conda and am trying to setup a CI pipeline for a bespoke requirement.

My understanding with the 'conda build' command is that internally it creates a temporary conda environment and uses this for evaluation of this build process. I am aware of this because it a version that I used last year that we upgraded, we had to change the meta.yaml file to have a new source folder entry for unit tests that it would then run against in this special folder.

**More context (sorry for waffle)**

Given the above, what I am looking to do is to extract the environment file once its run its operations e.g. dependency checks, unit tests etc..

If I were trying to extract (export) the env file for an environment, I would of course to the usual:

`conda export > [some_path]/env.yml`

The reason behind trying to get the environment during the 'conda build' process is for two reasons:

1.) Typically the developers tend to only list in the meta.yaml file the top level dependencies not all dependencies, and I need this list for a bespoke process down the line.
2.) (less vital but still good)
I can guarantee that the version built by the 'conda build' process (and all its dependencies) are valid.

- Sometimes there is the issue of the build running and then a lower level dependency version changing between the time of the build and the release.
- I do appreciate that the devs should be fixing all versions in the recipe but there are still sometimes some problems.

**Question**

Therefore, is it possible to retrieve/extract/export the environment file from the 'conda build' command-process?? Perhaps there is some flag? Or something I can script to run pre-build finishing?

**Possible solution I thought of**

Let process run, then script a step in my CI to create the environment and export the env file - I just don't want to add more time to the CI process though

Comment: I think the `--dirty` flag will retain the temporary `_build` environment. You could then find its location and do `conda env -p /path/to/_build/env > some_path/env.yml`.

Comment: Fantastic yes this is a great idea! As I can stick this in before purging this means I still have access. Many thanks.

The other alternative that our devops team discovered but not perfect, was in the meta.yaml file, you can add under the "commands:" section a command to export the env.yml file. So when the conda build had finished it would re-run and extract the environment - easy to do, but new conda build step needed to do it.

  commands:
    # Output the test results to the build source directory
    - 'conda env export  > {{ environ.get("ENVDIRECTORY") + "\environment.yml" }}'